# Redirect an Nginx Vhost/URL unless on a specific URL?

Tags: url, file-upload, nginx, url-rewriting, cloudflare

Would anyone have the code to put into an Nginx block somewhere for the following scenario.

I have our site going through Cloudflare (url.com) but they don't support uploads of more than 150mb, we have uploads up to 300mb. Their solution for this it to create a sub domain (upload.url.com) which isn't Cloudflare enabled and use that for uploads. Ive done this, no problem and hardcoded the links to the upload page to go via the upload URL. The problem is now, where my site has links which are just "/page" its going via upload.url.com/page, would there be a way in Nginx block to set it so anything going to upload.url.com just works on the upload pages I want it to go to and if they click back to any other part of the site it will make sure it loads up that page via "url.com"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name "upload.example.com";

    location ^~ /page {
        return 301 http://example.com$uri;
    }
}
```

Or if all your upload pages can be identified via a specific portion within the URL.

```
server {
    server_name "upload.example.com";

    location / {
        location ~* "^(?!.*?upload).*$" {
            return 301 http://example.com$uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you only have a single valid location.

```
server {
    server_name "upload.example.com";

    location = /upload-script {
        # Code to process upload
    }

    # Redirect anything else!
    location / {
        return 301 http://example.com$uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I input the specific URLs in the second example mate? Eg if my url is "upload.example.com/upload-file" how would I whitelist that as one to visit and anything else to be redirected to the example.com version

Comment: Extended my answer to include an example for this as well. I think it's even possible to leave out the surrounding `location / {}` block, but you'd have to test that.

Comment: Thank you, I think the last one is what I'll be able to work with, can I put multiple urls in location? or would I need to use multiple locations? There is a /upload-page and an /admin-upload too see, its just those two pages. Though I slightly worry as they are multiple page it might add characters to the url, so maybe /upload-script* ?

Comment: Ah ok, I should probably expand that I already have my host file setup as...

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name url.com www.url.com upload.url.com;
    root        /var/www/vhosts/production/current;
    index       index.html index.htm;
    charset     utf-8;

Comment: Is there anyway to make the change within that config, or should I make my upload.url.com a separate config file and point it to the same directory? As I can't make another server block here to specific domain only redirects...

Comment: It's definitely better to create a separate configuration file per subdomain. Regarding the two paths, it's faster if you create two separate `location` blocks that match the paths with `=`. Don't worry about the duplicated code within those blocks (old refactoring rule, if it's only twice leave it).

Comment: Ah, I think theres a miss understanding here. With this setup, its redirect my upload urls to the main url. So if I visit upload.example.com/upload its 301 redirecting back to example.com/upload. What I want is for upload.example.com to only come into affect on the (3) upload pages, which are upload.example.com/admin-upload/ upload.example.com/user-upload/ and upload.example.com/user-upload/#gf_1 any other requests to upload.example.com should redirect to the example.com version, which of course return 301 http://example.com$uri; does...

Comment: taking your last example, this would work, but I don't have "code to process upload" I just need them to access that page on the site, so how would I fill that box with what is intentionally "requests for upload.example.com/user-upload go through, everything else redirect to the example.com version?

Comment: Well, you definitely have some code in your other configuration file. Passing the request to some upstream server I suppose (PHP?). Same code goes in here.

Comment: ah ha, thats what I was missing - its a HUGE section of code (so I don't suppose there is a way to match all three locations in one block is there?)

Comment: You could create a separate file and use `include`, then you have a single place for it.

Comment: I just used location ^~ /(page1|page2|page3) to match my three pages, works a treat. Also told my main domain to redirect to upload version, so now I don't need to hard link to them either and its all neat 301 redirects so should be good for Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what you want correctly, you want to redirect any URI that isn't root to the main domain, try this

```
server {
  server_name upload.example.com;
  location = / {
    #pass to the upload script;
  }
  location / {
    # redirect to the main domain
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
  }
}
```